# why do I get a type error here?

Tags: haskell

I'm sitting on this for over 4 hours and can't wrap my head aroud it.
I try to run the following code:

```
top = 100 :: Int

couplesToOne num
    |num<0            = error "num<0"
    |num==0           = 0
    |num `mod` 2 == 0 = num `div` 2
    |num `mod` 2 == 1 = (num+1) `div` 2
    |otherwise        = error "otherwise"

numInBig n bigSide 
    |(bigSide^2 <= n) = couplesToOne (n-1)  
    |(bigSide^2 >  n) = couplesToOne (n-1) - (couplesToOne (floor(sqrt(bigSide^2 - n))))
    |otherwise        = error "otherwise"

ans = map (numInBig top) [3..((div top 4) + 1)]
```

and I get the following error message:

```
No instance for (RealFrac Int) arising from a use of `numInBig'
In the first argument of `map', namely `(numInBig top)'
In the expression: map (numInBig top) [3 .. ((div top 4) + 1)]
In an equation for `ans':
    ans = map (numInBig top) [3 .. ((div top 4) + 1)]
    enter code here
```

I figured out (probably?) that this is because of the "sqrt" that returns a float but that's why I added the floor that's supposed to return an Integral.

can you please help me?

Comment: Not only does `sqrt` *return* a float output, it also *expects* a float input. Try adding a `fromIntegral` in there.

Comment: By the way, to debug type errors it's very useful to annotate eacho top-level binding (at least) with its expected type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
top = 100 :: Int

couplesToOne num
    |num<0            = error "num<0"
    |num==0           = 0
    |num `mod` 2 == 0 = num `div` 2
    |num `mod` 2 == 1 = (num+1) `div` 2
    |otherwise        = error "otherwise"

numInBig n bigSide 
    |(bigSide^2 <= n) = couplesToOne (n-1)  
    |(bigSide^2 >  n) = couplesToOne (n-1) - couplesToOne (floor(sqrt(fromIntegral(bigSide^2 - n))))
    |otherwise        = error "otherwise"

ans = map (numInBig top) [3..((div top 4) + 1)]
```

You need an extra `fromIntegral` because `sqrt::Floating a => a -> a` is not defined on `Int`.

```
> ans
[50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,48,47,46,45,44,44,43,43,42,41,41]
```